# Can I use was instead?

Tags: sentence-construction

So I've learnt that in order to describe a cause that occurred due to my actions I can use the past perfect continuous, this also applies if I mention time.

> I was tired because I had been waiting for a long time.
> I forgot to call because I had been using my phone.
> They fell over because they had been jumping around.

I'd like to know would it be acceptable to use the past continuous instead?

> I was tired because I was waiting for too long.
> I forgot to call because I was on my phone.
> They fell over because they were jumping around.

Comment: All your was/were suggestions are fine.

Comment: As a close approximation you *always* can use the past tense instead of the past perfect.

Comment: So I'm assuming the "Had been" ones were incorrect or missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I was tired because I [was/had been] waiting for a long time.

Both are fine, and have more or less the same meaning.

In terms of connotations, "had been" connotes that the waiting happened first, and you may not have felt tired until after you were finished waiting, while "was" merely connotes that both events happened at some point in the past, maybe simultaneously or maybe sequentially. This is a fairly subtle difference and the average native speaker is unlikely to care too heavily about it.

> I forgot to call because I [was/had been] using my phone.

Both are fine. I don't see much practical difference in terms of connotations, because it is simply impossible to interpret the two events as sequential. You must have forgotten to call because you were using your phone *at the same time* as when you were supposed to call. Otherwise, the sentence makes little sense.

If you want to say that the prior phone call somehow distracted or upset you, and caused you to forget to make a subsequent phone call, you would need to be more explicit about that fact; such an inference is unlikely to be made merely because you used the past perfect.

> They fell over because they [were/had been] jumping around.

Both are fine. Again, I don't see much practical difference, because in this case it is impossible to interpret the events as simultaneous. They must have fallen over *immediately after* they were jumping around, at which point they were not jumping anymore because they were on the ground.